# How to store Elasticsearch data in rdb?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

hello? Due to a customer's request, we are in a situation where we need to input elasticsearch data into the rdb table.
Customers want this to happen in real time.
When inputting rdb data into elasticsearch, it appears a lot on Google, but I could not find a case where elasticsearch data is input in rdb.

Is it possible via logstash or elasticsearch pipeline?

Answer (score -1):

You get data in ES, then map to object and store to your rdb(I think you should use Java or Python, ...). if you want to use it, you should clear data in ES.